# Find records by comparing dates on the same record in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Say I have a model with three date fields:

- `created_at`
- `updated_at`
- `xyz_at`

How do I go about finding all records where `xyz_at` < `updated_at`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
records = YourModel.where('xyz_at < updated_at')
for record in records
  puts record.updated_at, record.xyz_at
end
```

Comment: I was trying to do just this but with xyz_at initially being nil. This doesn't work. Is there a better way to handle this besides making xyz_at defaulted to some time way in the past? `self.xyz_at  ||= Date.new(1979,12,13)`